# Create HIVE partitioned table HDFS location assistance

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeswax

Sure hope someone can help me out with creating external HIVE partitioned tables by  automatically adding data based on comma delimited files residing in an HDFS directory.  My understanding, or lack thereof, is that when you define a CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE, PARTITIONED, and providing it with a LOCATION, it should recursively scan/read each and every sub-directory, and load data into the newly create partitioned external table.  The following should provide some additional insight into my troubles…

```
Sample HDFS directory structure:<br>
/data/output/dt=2014-01-01<br>
/data/output/dt=2014-01-02<br>
/data/output/dt=2014-01-03   ...<br>
/data/output/dt=2014-05-21<br>
```

And each 'dt=' sub-directory contains the delimited file.

The following is an example of my CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE syntax:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE master_test (UID string,
    lname string,
    fname string,
    addr string,
    city string,
    state string,
    orderdate string,
    shipdate string)

    PARTITIONED BY (dt STRING)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
    LOCATION '/data/output/';
```

Upon the creation of my master_test external table, I would have thought that all of my delimited files would have already been contained within the table upon the CREATE.  The only way for me to get data into the newly defined external table is through an ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION statement, for example:  ALTER TABLE master_test ADD PARTITION (dt='2014-04-16').  Or, if I explicitly define the location of the delimited file, it will add the individual file the defined table.

Any suggestions or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use MSCK REPAIR to automatically discover the partitions.
Take a look at the doc: [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions%28MSCKREPAIRTABLE%29)

Comment: Gwen, thank you.  It worked like a charm!  For some reason, since I am a new member, it would not allow me to vote up your answer.

Comment: No worries. pay it forward by answering other questions :)

Comment: @GwenShapira After reading the document/link from apache that you provided, I was unclear as to whether or not it was possible to make partitions "truly" dynamic.  What I mean by that is, can a new directory be created say /data/output/dt=2014-01-01. and have it automatically added to future partition based queries without having to "add" the new partition to the Hive definition.  It seems like a potential similar to how a "multi-phase" commit error can cause cascading failures in RDBMs.

Comment: You must add the directory to Hive metadata somehow. There's no automated discovery process. So either an "add" or "msck" command is a must. Not sure how its related to multi-phase commit - until the "add" command is run, the table doesn't change at all.

Comment: The term "dynamic partitions" refers to inserts done through Hive (and updates in the future). If you enable dynamic partitions you don't need to specify which partition you insert into, and new partitions will be created automatically. These will be immediately visible, no need to run "add" on those.